# Azure deployment issue: partial view cannot be loaded when deployed to Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-devops

This issue only happened in our systest environment. All files are there in the cloud.

This is an web app based on ASP.NET MVC5

This is the source code on the App Services:

[image]

The same issue happened to me when loading the css and js files:

[Bootstrap icons are loaded locally but not when online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664287/bootstrap-icons-are-loaded-locally-but-not-when-online)

[Bundling with MVC4 not working after I publish to azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898429/bundling-with-mvc4-not-working-after-i-publish-to-azure)

I fixed it by renaming the virtual path for the bundling.

Generally speaking, the web pages feel like we roll back our code a few weeks ago. It feels like something is cached in Azure.

Is there any I missed in the app/ web.config? or some settings in the Azure side that I can tweak?

Comment: The Index page can be displayed successfully, ReportPayroll is the partial view for the index. When I navigate to the ReportPayroll. I cannot find anything there. However, the file and everything is there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apologize guys, actually this is a permission issue.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a discovery issue where MVC is looking where you are not expecting.

Try this in your call to render the Partial.

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/ReportDashboard/Quarterly/ReportPayroll.cshtml")
```

Comment: I use `@Html.Partial("Quarterly/ReportPayroll")` it works fine in my local environment. MVC is able to find the relative path for the partial view.

Comment: I just tried making the changes according to @raterus. Actually it didn't work as expected.